# Fantasy book series where a woman gains magic by having twins?

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book series where one of main characters gains magic by having twins. She was not born with magic but after an arranged marriage with a magician she gains part of the power of her children.

The setting is sort of pseudo crusade era except with powerful magicians. There's another main character on another continent who is training at a school I think. The whole first book seemed to be build up for the war that was coming later in the series.

I only read the first book and can't remember the name of it or the series. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/12974280?